# Strong Induction Proof Help

Tags: induction

I'm expected to proof by strong induction the following:

- Give proof (using strong  induction)  that every odd
  number is of the form 2n+1

I'm not sure how to approach this problem. Isn't this false because you can portray an odd number also as 2n-1?

Comment: No it's true.  It means that every odd number can be expressed in this form, not that there's no other way to do it.

Comment: You can write an odd number as $2n+1$ for some $n$ or as $2n-1$ for some (different) $n$.  $13$ for instance is $2\times6+1$ and it is $2\times 7-1$.

Comment: How do you define "odd number"?